# input event <nil>

Tags: events

*I don't know what I did* caused Emacs to emit such a message:

```
<nil> <wheel-down> is undefined
```

Screenshot:

[image]

---

How did I issue this input event?  
In other words, what does this `<nil>` stand for?

---

Now I know how to reproduce it:

(`emacs -Q`, of course)

Put the mouse pointer

- anywhere above the *tool bar*
- at the edge of a *frame*

, then wheel.

As *Drew* and *db48x* suggested, I reported it as [bug#63054](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2023-04/msg01553.html).

---

emacs-version: 28.2
system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: Show your mouse/key-binding code that binds `wheel-down` etc. Do, somewhere, use `[nil]` in a binding? (First, repro with `emacs -Q`.) Provide a recipe that's step-by-step, showing what modes you're in, etc.

Comment: @Drew: I will show it once I can, of course. But currently, I don't know what I did that led to such a message. And, there's no code that binds `wheel-down` in my configuration.

Comment: @Drew: updated :-)

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question - in the question itself. If the question is how you issued that event, the answer is that you rolled the mouse wheel over the menu bar. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've added a mention that you see the same thing with `emacs -Q`, and you see it when you roll the mouse wheel over a menu-bar menu:

On MS Windows, at least, I see the same thing.

And I see it in every Emacs version back to 22. It may also be the case for 21 -- I don't have that version. (It's not the case for Emacs 20, because that treats the menu bar the same as the rest of the window wrt wheel rolling.)

Is this a bug? I doubt it, especially based on the longstanding behavior. I suspect it's just undocumented behavior. But maybe someone can find somewhere where this is documented.

If no one does that here, you might consider filing a bug report, `M-x report-emacs-bug`, at least to get this documented.

Comment: Thanks for testing each version, +1. |||| "*I suspect it's just undocumented behavior.*" --- I'll spend some time trying (and that's it) to search the documentation and see whether the behavior is described. |||| "*you might consider filing a bug report*" --- I will, if I fail to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Not reproducible with Gtk+ Emacs 28.2 on Linux, FWIW. There, rolling the mouse wheel over the menu bar has no visible effect and doesn't put anything in `*Messages*` either.  (Also `emacs -Q`; had to be, my personal configuration turns off the menu bar.)

Comment: I reported it. I guess you may be interested in it: see my updated question.

Comment: Yes, I see it's Emacs bug [#63054](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=63054). Closed as not a bug but a feature - an undocumented feature. (Why shouldn't the `<nil>` event description be documented?)

Comment: "*Closed as not a bug but a feature*" --- It doesn't matter, I'll *change the title of the question* (I'm not sure whether the terminology I used is concise and standard, you can edit it) so that even if it's not documented, other users can *easily* find this question via the Internet and notice the bug#63054 and this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You should see this instead:

```
<menu-bar> <wheel-down> is undefined
<menu-bar> <double-wheel-down> is undefined
```

Does it still happen if you start Emacs with -Q? If it does, then file a bug report using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If it does not, then bisect your init file until you find the part that breaks it.

Comment: yes, with `-Q`.  I will report it tomorrow to see what developers will reply.  May I ask what you see?  (I think I should add version information to the question.)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior described in the question and see the behavior described in the answer above ( GNU Emacs 29.0.60, Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon).